# Can't run jupyter notebooks in vscode, IPyKernel not installed into interpreter, Windows 10, Ananconda Distributor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I know there are several posts related to this error, but so far none of the solutions I've read has worked, also it seems to be dependent on the software versions, so I decided to make my own post,

The linked image shows the error message I get from vscode, when it tries to install IPyKernel it says it is already installed.

[Error message in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCaZQ.png)

I am using python 3.7.9, conda version 4.9.2, vscode 1.52, windows 10, and the conda base environment.

Please let me know if you need any additional information or logs,

thanks in advance I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've identified and resolved a related issue. The fix can be found in the attached VSIX.

Please could you enable logging for the Jupyter extension as follows:

1.- Open user settings (Preferences: Open User Settings & go into Jupyter->Logging
Change the value to debug and Reload VS Code.

Install this copy of the VSIX: https://pvsc.blob.core.windows.net/extension-builds-jupyter-public/ms-python-insiders.vsix

2.- Download & install using the command Extensions; Install from VSIX

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn to the directory which says `ipykernel` is already installed and delete the file `ipykernel` or directly empty the folder `site-packages`;
2. Open the integrated Terminal(Ctrl+Shift+`), activate the conda environment then run the command:

   ```
    pip install ipykernel
   ```

Make Sure the interpreter used in jupyter should be selected rightly:
[image]